# How component is getting data from redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Following along the [example async app](https://redux.js.org/advanced/example-reddit-api) from the Redux documentation, and I really don't understand how the component `AsyncApp` has access to the posts that are fetched async.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { selectedSubreddit, postsBySubreddit } = state
  const {
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated,
    items: posts
  } = postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }
 
  return {
    selectedSubreddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
}
```

Questions:

**1-** what is this expression: `postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit]`? Accessing a function with brackets? Does this set up the component with the props `posts` from `const { selectedSubreddit, posts, isFetching, lastUpdated } = this.props`

**2-** They are able to send `<Posts posts={posts} />` but where are they getting those posts from in the first place!? Why are they a part of the props!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this expression: `postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit]`?
>   Accessing a function with brackets?

No, `postsBySubreddit` is **not a function**, its an object basically, and `[]` (bracket notation) is for accessing the object values by some dynamic key.

Check this snippet:

```js
let obj = {a:1, b:2};
let k = 'b';                  //k will have the property name
console.log('value of b = ', obj[k]);
```

As per [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using
>   the dot notation or the bracket notation.

You are getting confused with [Destucturing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation), See what exactly is happening there:

```
const selectedSubreddit = state.selectedSubreddit; 
const postsBySubreddit = state.postsBySubreddit;

const data = postsBySubreddit[selectedSubreddit] || { isFetching: true, items: []}
const isFetching = data.isFetching; 
const lastUpdated = data.lastUpdated; 
const lastUpdated = data.lastUpdated;
```

> Where are they getting those posts from in the first place!?

Those values are getting passed from redux store. `mapStateToProps` will get the store as first argument and from there we can access any data. We use [Provider](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) that will provide the store data to all the connected component.

As per **[DOC](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store)**:

> Provider makes the Redux store available to the connect() calls in the
>   component hierarchy. Normally, you can’t use connect() without
>   wrapping a parent or ancestor component in `<Provider>`

Comment: Oh ok, well I suppose what I'm so confused about is: where are they getting the posts from in the props? Don't those have to be fetched async? How does the app know to have them in the props?

Comment: see, that data is getting passed from redux store, `mapStateToProps` will get the store as first argument, and from there you can access data of any reducer. About how component is getting the data is, there is a HOC `Provider` that pass the store data to all the components connected to redux store, also it will trigger re-rendering whenever any change happen to redux store, so even though api call are async whenever store get updatedcomponent will automatically get the updated data :)

Comment: Very helpful thank you Mayank! I think I have some trouble with my app code then, if you have the time could you take a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48880658/react-redux-action-creator-undefined-in-mapstatetoprops